# ¿Porque me pasa esto en Java?

Tags: java, string

tengo un código cuyo objetivo es eliminar el caracter indicado en wordactual a la cadena que le paso por parámetro (tanto mayusculas como minusculas). Pensaba que iba bien y de hecho estaba construyendo un programa más complejo sobre este código ya que probé con otras letras, pero al evaluar en particular la 'e', se salta una letra en la cadena! Porqué me pasa esto?

```
public static String ModificarPalabra ( String palabra ) { 

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(palabra);
    int longitud = palabra.length();

        char wordactual = 'e'; 

        for (int j = 0; j < longitud; j++){


            if (wordactual == sb.charAt(j) || wordactual == Character.toLowerCase(sb.charAt(j)) || wordactual == Character.toLowerCase(sb.charAt(j)) ){ 
                System.out.println(sb.charAt(j));
                sb.deleteCharAt(j);
                longitud -= 1;
             }

        }

    return sb.toString();
}
```

La cadena que le paso: "dedaDrERaeeChAHEcEF"

y, viendo las letras que va eliminando, me devuelve esto:

e
E
e
E
E

ddaDrRa**e**ChAHcF

Comment: Para más claridad en las búsquedas de los usuarios que puedan responder a tu pregunta, indica un **título más descriptivo** de cual es tu problema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te doy la bienvenida a Stackoverflow.

Hay varios errores en tu código.

1. Estás usando el mismo `StringBuilder` para almacenar el valor final y a la vez comparar el valor inicial. Eso hace que, cuando haya dos caracteres que sean iguales seguidos, haya una confusión al momento de borrar ese caracter. Pasa con la `e` porque en la cadena hay dos `e` seguidas. Pero si pones dos `a` seguidas o cualquier otro pasará lo mismo. Esto se resuelve dejando intacta la cadena inicial por una parte y creando un nuevo `StringBuilder` que irá agregando los valores que deban estar en el resultado final.
2. El ciclo `for` también es algo confuso y redundante. No necesitas restar 1 a `longitud` en el cuerpo del bucle; no necesitas una comparación tan redundante, basta con convertir a minúscula el carácter y hacer una comparación sobre seguro (ver respuesta con una propuesta mejor en este sentido).
3. Para este caso, no es necesario crear una variable `longitud`.

Así debería funcionar sin problemas:

```
public static String ModificarPalabra ( String palabra ) { 

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    char wordactual = 'e'; 
    for (int j = 0; j < palabra.length( ); j++){
        Character charActual=Character.toLowerCase(palabra.charAt(j));
        if (charActual != wordactual) {
            sb.append(palabra.charAt(j));           
        }
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```

**Salida:**

```
ddaDrRaChAHcF
```

Comment: Gracias antes que nada por tu respuesta. Pero quería eliminar tanto las mayúsculas como las minúsculas... Si pongo una letra mayuscula no me elimina los caracteres.

Comment: @user143229 entiendo. En ese caso, sólo tienes que forzar a minúscula el valor con el que vas a comparar, poniendo esto: **`char wordactual = Character.toLowerCase('E');`** en lugar de : `char wordactual = 'E';` así lo hará en ambos casos. Se podría hacer también dentro del bucle con algo así: `if ( charActual != Character.toLowerCase(wordactual) ) {` pero dado que es un valor fijo el código queda más optimizado convirtiéndolo una sola vez a minúscula.